# Partial updating a ManyToMany field, but keeping its get representation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been scratching my head about this problem for a couple of hours now. Basically, I have two models: `User` and `Project`:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField("Email Address", unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="avatars", default="avatars/no_avatar.png")
    first_name = models.CharField("First name", max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField("Last name", max_length=50)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
```

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=8, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(
        "Status",
        max_length=1,
        choices=[("O", "Open"), ("C", "Closed")],
        default="O",
    )
    description = models.CharField("Description", max_length=3000, default="")

    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="project_owner"
    )
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="project_participants", blank=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I use standard `ModelViewSet`s for both of them, nothing changed. Then there's my `Project` serializer:

```py
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = "__all__"

    status = serializers.CharField(source="get_status_display", required=False)
    owner = UserSerializer()
    participants = UserSerializer(many=True)
```

I use `UserSerializer`s here, because having them achieved first of my two goals:

- I wanted to get the user data when getting the project from the API -> `owner` is a serialized `User` with all the fields, same for participants, but it's a list of users
- I want to be able to partially update the `Project`, for example add a participant

So I searched through the docs and SO and I always found answers that answer one of those questions, but never both of them.

The thing with my second goal is: when I do the partial update (via PATCH, of course), I get the response that: `"Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."` when I pass a list of ints (user ids) for the participants. I thought: okay, maybe I have to pass the whole user data to change it. But then I realised: when I remove the `UserSerializer` from `ProjectSerializer` - passing just the list of ints in Postman works just fine. And that is a life saver, cuz who wants to create a request with a whole bunch of data, when I can just pass user ids.

But then of course when I remove the `UserSerializer`, when I call `get project`, I get `participants: [1,2,3,4,...]`, not `participants: [{"id": 1, "name": "John", ...}, ...}]`. And I really want this behavior, because I don't want to make additional API calls just to get the users' data by their IDs.

So summing up my question is: Is there a way to leave those serializers in place but still be able to partially update my model without having to pass whole serialized data to the API (dicts instead of IDs)? Frankly, I don't care about the serializers, so maybe the question is this: Can I somehow make it possible to partially update my Products' related fields like `owner` or `participants` just by passing the related entities IDs **while still** maintaining an ability to get my projects with those fields expanded (serialized entities - dicts, instead of just IDs)?

@Edit:

My view:

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from projects.models import Project
from projects.api.serializers import ProjectSerializer


class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    lookup_field = "name"

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return Project.objects.all()
        else:
            return Project.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user.id)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user, participants=[self.request.user])
```

Answer:

To anyone reading this, I've solved this problem and I actually created a base class for all my viewsets that I want this behavior to be in:

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response


class ReadWriteViewset:
    write_serializer_class = None
    read_serializer_class = None

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop("partial", False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        write_serializer = self.write_serializer_class(
            instance=instance,
            data=request.data,
            partial=partial,
        )

        write_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(write_serializer)

        read_serializer = self.read_serializer_class(instance)

        if getattr(instance, "_prefetched_objects_cache", None):
            # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
            # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
            instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

        return Response(read_serializer.data)
```

Then you use it kinda like in [here](https://github.com/vintasoftware/drf-rw-serializers)

Comment: Hi, can you add your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using a `ModelViewSet`. You could use different serializers for different methods.

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in ['create', 'update']:
            return WriteProjectSerializer # your serializer not using `UserSerializer` that works for updating

        return ProjectSerializer # your default serializer with all data
```

Edit for using different serializers in same method:

```
# you can override `update` and use a different serializer in the response. The rest of the code is basically the default behavior
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    instance = self.get_object()
    write_serializer = WriteProjectSerializer(data=request.data)

    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    instance = self.perform_update(serializer)

    read_serializer = ProjectSerializer(instance)


    if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
        # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
        # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
        instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

    return Response(read_serializer.data)
```

A good way to see the default code for all these methods is using [Classy DRF](https://www.cdrf.co/3.12/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html). You can see all methods that come with using `ModelViewSet` and use that code with some changes. Here I'm using the default code for `update` but changing for a new serializer for the response.

Comment: Hmm, and `WriteProjectSerializer` would be the same as `ProjectSerializer`, but not containing the nested serializer fields, right?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. The only question, when I update or partial update, the response that I receive still contains plain ids instead of objects. When I do `list` or `get`, I get the objects. Is there a way around the first case, or does it have to be this way?

Comment: Oh, in that case maybe you could overwrite the different mixin methods and do the different serialization before and after saving. Check my edit.

Comment: Oh yeah, let me test if that works for me, but I think it will :)

Comment: Okay, this is great. I had to make some modifications, because for example: `self.perform_update(write_serializer)` doesn't return an instance, you need to somehow get it again, like with `get_object`. And by the way, the site you linked - gold. Thank you very much!

Comment: And by the way, I don't have to call `get_object`, since the instance is changed in place, so `instance` will be the instance that got changed via `perform_update`

Comment: Great, glad it helped

Comment: @dabljues BTW, there is the same thing but for django class based views. Check [Classy cvb](https://ccbv.co.uk/)

Comment: Do you mean `UpdateView` and `BaseUpdateView`? If so, they are nice, but if I work strictly with DRF (I keep my frontend completely separate, different app), those would be kinda useless in my case, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, they are useful if you are using full stack django and not rest API. Maybe it was useful for other projects. But ignore it if you are only using separated front and back ends.